# How can I use multiple .contains() inside a .when() in pySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to create classes in a new column, based on existing words in another column. For that, I need to include multiple .contains() conditions. But none of the one I tried work.

```py
def classes_creation(data):
    df = data.withColumn("classes", when(data.where(F.col("MISP_RFW_Title").like('galleys') | F.col("MISP_RFW_Title").like('coffee')),"galleys") ).otherwise(lit(na))
    return df
# RETURNS ERROR
```

```py
def classes_creation(data):
     df = data.withColumn("classes", when(col("MISP_RFW_Title").contains("galleys").contains("word"), 'galleys').otherwise(lit(na))
     return df
# RETURNS COLUMN OF NA ONLY
```

```py
def classes_creation(data):
     df = data.withColumn("classes", when(col("MISP_RFW_Title").contains("galleys" | "word"), 'galleys').otherwise(lit(na))
     return df
# RETURNS COLUMN OF NA ONLY
```

Comment: does not work since I need a contain condition, or a like. They use operator such as == or < or >.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirements correctly, you can use regex for matching with `rlike`

```
data.withColumn("classes", when(col("MISP_RFW_Title").rlike("galleys|word"), 'galleys').otherwise('a'))
```

or maybe if you have different columns, you can use something like this

```
data.withColumn("classes", when((col("MISP_RFW_Title").contains("galleys")|col("MISP_RFW_Title").contains("word")), 'galleys').otherwise('a'))
```

Comment: I got the following error when implementing your code : `in when
    raise TypeError("condition should be a Column")
TypeError: condition should be a Column`

Comment: @J.Perez works fine for me.. what is the Spark Version you are using? can you share some of the data?